# commutator of the groupe $Q_{4n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to detemine the commutator of the group $Q_{4n}$

defined by:

$Q_{4n}=\left\{e,\sigma,...\sigma^{2n-1},\nu,\nu\sigma,...,\nu\sigma^{2n-1}\right\}$

Where $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}e^{\pi \frac{i}{n}}&0\\0&e^{-\pi \frac{i}{n}}\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\nu=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $\nu^2$?$ $$ $$ $

Comment: $=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $\nu^2 = \begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix} = \sigma^n$

Comment: and how does that answer the question?

Comment: I'm just experimenting aka thinking out loud

Comment: See the comments at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429730/abelianization-of-a-well-known-group#comment5018689_2429730).

Comment: it is a duplicate also of [thisone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429863/existence-of-an-automorphism)

Answer (score 0):

- $\sigma^m \sigma^n \sigma^{-m} \sigma^{-n} = e$
- $\nu^m \nu^n \nu^{-m} \nu^{-n} = e$
- $\sigma^m (\nu \sigma^{n}) \sigma^{-m} (\nu \sigma^{n})^{-1} = \sigma^m \nu \sigma^{-m} \nu^{-1} = \sigma^{2m}$

Therefore the commutator is $\langle \sigma^2 \rangle$.

---

P.S. $Q_{4n} / \langle \sigma^2 \rangle \cong V_4$

Comment: In particular, I want to show that there exists an automorphism $\phi$ of $Q_8$ such that $\phi(\sigma)=\nu$ and $\phi(\nu)=\sigma\nu$.


Where $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}e^{\pi \frac{i}{2}}&0\\0&e^{-\pi \frac{i}{2}}\end{pmatrix}$ and $\nu=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $V_4$ is if $n$ is even, otherwise it is $C_4$